# PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name error after running export DATABASE_URL=postgres://$(whoami)

Tags: database, postgresql, pg, rails-postgresql

I received this error after running

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://$(whoami)
```

on the command line. Now when I run the command

```
$$ rake db:migrate
```

This is the full error

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "Jillian" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

How can I fix postgres?

PS I was following this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup to set up pg for a python app, but I may have an old version of pg. I'm trying to at least get postgres back to how it was before I ran that^

Answer (score 14, accepted):

....And the answer you've all been waiting for:

If you've messed up your development environment by running export `DATABASE_URL=...`, if you'e in a similar sitaution to the one above and already set up your environments within each project, resolve this issue by running

```
unset DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: Thanks, its like I was blind to that line in my profile!

Comment: Thank god for you

Comment: Is that possible even on Jenkins instance ?

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to change **/etc/hosts** file

In my **application.yml** file was defined:

```
databases:
  crm:
    adapter: postgresql
    host: postgresql
```

and error was looked like

```
PG::ConnectionBad:
  could not translate host name "postgresql" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

therefore I've edit my **/etc/hosts** file (with sudo):
**sudo vim /etc/hosts**
and have added next row

```
127.0.0.1       postgresql
```

after that everything works fine